# Can I use "drag it me"?

Tags: expressions

Can I use the expression "drag it me"?

It means "it (something) is dragging me".

Comment: Please explain what you mean or give more context or I will vote to close here. Also, please look up the definition of the verb to drag in a dictionary. [from **the** Arctic?]

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not a complete sentence or grammatical phrase.

"It drags me" would be the correct word order.

But it would not make much sense to a native speaker, because the meaning of "drags" is not clear in your example. I guess that you want to say "it bothers (or "annoys" or "upsets") me."

There are slang uses of "drag" that are close. For example:

"This class is a drag" -- boring, tedious, tiring. But you would not say "This class drags me."

If you are using "drag" in the conventional sense (pulling along a surface), you might say, "The car dragged me" or "I saw the lion drag the gazelle."

It's hard to imagine the circumstances, but this could happen, I guess:

"The robot vacuum catches my pajama leg every time it goes by. Then it drags me down the hall."

Comment: Surely there is a literal meaning to *it drags me*. Something or someone is pulling me along the ground. Either to get me to safety or its lair!

Answer (score 2):

As @user8356 points out, you have the word order wrong. "It drags me" is a complete and valid sentence.

Whether it expresses the idea you want ... what are you trying to say? To "drag" something literally means to pull it without it providing any assistance. Like, "I dragged the heavy box across the floor." If you drag a person, that means he is not walking with you, you are pulling him while he hangs limp, like if he is injured, or actively resists, like you are trying to force him to go somewhere he doesn't want to go.

"Drag" is also use metaphorically to describe someone or something being forced or pressured to do something he/she/it does not want to do. Like, "I didn't want to buy a minivan but my wife dragged me there."